# How find table column with different values -rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Case:

```
table - movie:
  columns:
    rating:
    title:
```

Query 1- get all

```
 Movie.all(:order => "title ASC");
```

Query 2- get with rating="G" || rating="K"  ---Not working

```
ratingsArr=["G","K"]; also can be = [] =>real code params[:ratings] .. 
Movie.all(:order => "title ASC", ratingsArr);
```

How should I build Query 2? `ratingsArr` may or may not be empty. User set params, according them `ratingsArr` has the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `Movie.where(:rating => ratingsArr).order("title ASC")`

Being new, you should read the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and perhaps the [API documentation for ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

Comment: Edited . sorry, I forgot. There are actually a couple of ways to do it, this one is clear though.

Comment: ratingsArr == [] not return nothing  - it should return  all items

Comment: You'll need to make a special case for that using `if ratingsArr.empty?`. It's *supposed* to return nothing if you tell it to select all values that are in an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Movie.where( params[:ratings].present? ? {:rating => params[:ratings]} : {} ).
  order("title ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [SQL IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator by doing: `Movie.where(:rating => ratings_array).order("title ASC")`

Note that I changed `ratingsArr` to `ratings_array`. This is code convention for Ruby. CamelDot is only used for Class names. In variables words are seperated by `_`